# Is there a way to re-ask or refresh a question?

Tags: feature-request

I have just run across a question on Stack Overflow that was asked and answered last year.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717836/kohana-or-codeigniter

The answer to this question is time-sensitive in the fact that if the same question was posed today, it may receive a different answer.

It would be interesting to see a feature that allowed you to fire a request (probably with a limit of one request per 6-12 months per question) to have each answerer of a question indicate whether or not they still stand by the answer they provided.

Is there an already established etiquette for re-asking a question?

Comment: See example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294355/php-yaml-parsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Offer a bounty?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got edit rights, you could put in an edit asking if anything has changed.  That'll at least bump it to the front page and encourage answers.

Edit:  Alternately, ask a new question.  Be absolutely sure to reference the old question, and specifically ask for differences between then and now, otherwise, it'll be closed as a dupe real fast.  It's still going to be controversial, but it might be considered acceptable.

Comment: Is this acceptable behavior? It seems reminiscent of the annoying one-line "bump" comments that plague forums.

Comment: If the idea is to see if the people who didn't answer last week will answer this week, then the bump is annoying.  If it's to see if last year's answer still holds this year, it serves a purpose.  That's how I see it, anyway.